# Append a string at the start of each element in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

I have a list of strings

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>() { "MyItem1", "MyItem2", "MyItem3" };
```

How do I append "Thisis" at the start of each element in the list so that the new list becomes

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>() { "ThisisMyItem1", "ThisisMyItem2", "ThisisMyItem3" };
```

Comment: Hint: first consider whether you want to create a *new* list, or modify the *existing* list. LINQ makes the first option very easy.

Comment: I can have both options if possible can  you guide please

Comment: For clarity, "append" means to stick something to the end. I think you meant to say "prefix"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) to *project* a collection into a new collection, modifying each element in that projection.  Something as simple as:

```
var modifiedStrings = strings.Select(s => $"Thisis{s}");
```

Note that this will create an `IEnumerable<string>`.  If you *need* it to be a `List<string>` (that is, if you specifically need it to have the features of a `List<>` such as accessing elements by index) then you can append `.ToList()` onto any `IEnumerable<>`:

```
var modifiedStrings = strings.Select(s => $"Thisis{s}").ToList();
```

Comment: This is the answer. Need to import System.Linq

Comment: Almost certainly the OP would want to call the `.ToList()` extension method as well. Would be worth mentioning, otherwise they may not understand why they now have an `IEnumerable<string>` instead of a `List<string>`

Answer (score 3):

To create a *new* list you can use *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

List<string> newStrings = strings
  .Select(item => $"Thisis{item}")
  .ToList();
```

or create and loop:

```
List<string> newStrings = new List<string>(strings.Count);

foreach (var item in strings)
  newStrings.Add($"Thisis{item}")
```

If you want to *modify* existing `strings`, just loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.Count; ++i)
  strings[i] = $"Thisis{strings[i]}";
```